# Better way to write this method with this pattern?

Tags: c#

I have written a lot of methods and I want to time how long it takes for them to run.

```
     public void myMethod(){
         startTiming();
         doLotsOfStuff();
         stopTiming();
     }
```

I am not only timing, I am also doing some other stuff before AND after the doLotsOfStuff() method.

I was wondering if there is a better/smarter way to do this in C# to achieve lesser amount of lines/coding needed for this particular pattern.

Comment: You have 3 lines of code, that seems about as small as you'll get. What exactly do you want to shorten?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class.

```
var s = new StopWatch();
public void myMethod(){
     s.Start();
     doLotsOfStuff();
     s.Stop();
     Debug.Print(s.Elapsed.ToString());
 }
```

Not much you can do about the lines of code... You need one line to start the timer, one line to stop the timer, and one line to print the results.

You might be able to pass your method into a timer function that takes a `Func<T>`, but you'll need a bunch of overloads to handle all of the different signatures your methods may have, and it will muddle your design.  More trouble than it is worth.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a LOT of these methods, and want to be able to turn this before/after logging on and off, you might take a look at [Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with lots of similar methods, like no parameters, then you can create a benchmarking method like `Robert Harvey` detailed, but that accepts a delegate. Then your method would just need to invoke the delegate instead of calling it directly. As an option, you could have the method return either a TimeSpan, which is the measurement of time within the `StopWatch`, or return the `StopWatch` itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the `using` construct with a handle object to roughly measure how long it takes to pass through its code block.

```
...

using (new TimerHandle(time => /* timing behavior */)) {
    doLotsOfStuff();
}

...

class TimerHandle : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Action<TimeSpan> callback
    private readonly Stopwatch timer;

    public TimerHandle(Action<TimeSpan> callback)
    {
        this.callback = callback;
        this.timer = new Stopwatch();
        this.timer.Start();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        timer.Stop();
        callback(timer.Elapsed);
    }
}
```

Upon rereading your question, I noticed that you are looking to perform behavior before and after the code in question. You might want to consider wrapping `TimerHandle` so that a single method or property can perform such behavior.

```
static IDisposable Measure
{
    get
    {
        // before behavior
        return new TimerHandle(time => {
            // timing behavior
            // after behavior
        });
    }
}

using (Measure) { doLotsOfStuff(); }
using (Measure) { andOtherStuff(); }
```